# Get all data from sqlite and send to server in a for loop

Tags: java, android, web-services, sqlite

Is it possible to retrieve all data from sqlite database and send it to server to create content I´ve done this successfully for one record but I would like to send all records from my database is that possible ?

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "url/rest/node");
            httppost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);

            try {

                data.open();
                // String json = data.composeJSONfromSQLite();

                Cursor cc = data.getallEntries();
                if (cc.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= cc.getCount(); i++) {
                        // add raw json to be sent along with the HTTP POST
                        // request
                        //Double peso=cc.getDouble(cc.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.ENTRY_USER_WEIGHT));


                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title:",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.ENTRY_USER_value))));  
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.ENTRY_othervalue))));  


                        //se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");
                        httppost.setHeader("Accept","application/json");

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        HttpResponse response = httpclient
                                .execute(httppost);
                        String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response
                                .getEntity());
                        Log.i("se", jsonResponse.toString());
                    System.out.println("count do add"+ cc.getCount());
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error adding ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: a better implementation for this kind of thing is using a `Service`
Make an IntentService, that runs time to time in the background, checks for any non-synced data in your database...and sends it using an AsyncTask.....

It is always advised to send data in small chunks of packets

Comment: replace `if (cc.moveToFirst()) {` with `while (cc.moveToNext())`

Comment: (and obviously remove the first `return 0;`, which serves no purpose anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Send only one request with all data.

Comment: i disagree...what if the data fails in between??
you will have to send the whole data again...
its always better to send data in chunks of small

Comment: Can you provide me some example how to do that?

Comment: Atish, i agree with you, but its depend how many data to send, 1000 rows for example is better send in chunks of small, but can create a cache data for data until the data has sent.